# Employer's client is offering to hire me after I gave resignation notice to my employer

Tags: job-offer, ethics

**TLDR:** Is it a good idea to accept job offer from an employer's client, after I resigned to join another company.

I work at an IT consultancy as a project manager.

I am leading a large IT project for a well funded startup. This client came to us because they know me, they worked with me few years ago on another project. They are super demanding and will push the team hard. I have a love/hate relationship with them, I enjoyed their vision, passion, and drive to make disruptive products but I hate the long hours and lack of personal time while working with them.

I worked with my current employer for 5 years now and was promoted 3 times. The promotions gave me better pay. However, I am not satisfied with the work I am doing, the truth is I have never been satisfied. I always wanted to be an architect, I have studied for 9 years to one day become one. Two years ago I passed the AWS certifications, now I upgraded it to the highest one.

Strangely, I am now also very interested in project management. I recently joined one of the best business schools in the country to attend night classes. I was slowly accepting my new role.

However, last week I got an unexpected offer from a good company. They want me to join as an architect. I was super excited, I didn't ask for a hike but they still gave a small hike.

I informed my company. They unwillingly accepted my resignation and a bit of back and forth.

When the client heard about this, he called and made me an offer. He owns another company with specialises in proving high-end consulting to big companies. Honestly, this is a dream job and pay is far better.

The problem... I will end up managing the same project. I will become the client's representative to my current employer. I am afraid things will get complicated. Will I be seen as a "traitor"?

Also, I am afraid maybe this is a temporary measure by the client, I asked and he said it is not the case.

The client also promised that he will get written permission from my company for me to join him from my employer so that there will not be any legal issues.

**My dilemma:**

1) Do I take a big risk and go to client. They know me and value me.

2) Do I go to the new company and start fresh. I will have to earn everyone's trust and respect.

And to make things more difficult to choose. COVID-19 is causing a new recession.

Comment: Before accepting any job with a client you need to check your own contract to make sure you can work for a client or whether you need to wait for a period of time. Also its common for companies to contractually agree to not poach or employ staff from either party so you would need to somehow check this as well.

Comment: @UIO Both contracts have restrictions. However, client is saying he can get the company to give in writing that they have no objection.

Comment: This is risky because there is no guarentee your employer will allow this. If they don't, you loose the opportunity and also flag to your employer you want to leave.

Comment: @UIO I've already resigned to join another company. I am on my notice period.

Comment: Ok, but both sides still need to agree to this

Comment: You have accepted another offer right? Ensure you do not pull out of that until you have everything in writing from this one

Comment: @Bee yes of course, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You have already accepted an offer with another company.  Presumably, you like this new company enough to leave your current company.  Backing out now, just because the client has made you an offer, would be unprofessional and could burn bridges with your current employer and the new company.

There is also the legal aspect.  It is nice that the client has offered to provide you with written permission to join their company, but that has no bearing on your contract and agreements with your current company.  You could end up in legal trouble, and with the current pandemic situation this would not be a good time to have to deal with that.

Comment: The client offered to obtain a written no objection certificate from my employer for me. I don't know if that has any value.

Comment: also, i haven't officially accepted the offer from the new company. I have till Monday to accept.

Comment: Why did you resign from your current company without accepting an offer for another company?

Comment: I was going to accept the offer immediately. But that is when this client called me.